# Docusign REST API: Get all Envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I am making query for the rest API for getting all envelopes.

Following are documents in UI
[image]

When I query using envelop list changes with proper from date and to date and account id

It gives me only 1st and last document as below.

[image]

Comment: I believe this might be as designed, when you make the Envelopes: listStatusChanges request I believe it only lists the envelopes that you (your DocuSign user identity) has sent as signature requests, not envelopes that others have sent to you.  I haven't had time to test this, will try to soon.

Comment: Thanks Ergin but I think it should list all the envelope in my inbox or I am part of it. Don't you think so?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [GetSearchFolders](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Folders/Folders/search/) api to retrieve all the envelopes

Example:
The following GET request retrieves all the envelopes in the last 30 days.

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/search_folders/all
```

Other Search Folder Queries.

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/search_folders/drafts
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/search_folders/awaiting_my_signature
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/search_folders/completed
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/search_folders/out_for_signature
```

Comment: how to get all envelopes without knowing folders?

Comment: @ScanQR, you could first get a  list all of the folders beforehand: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/folders/folders/list/ and then search for reach folder.